# Limit result to 1

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, single-page-application

I have this Spring JPA repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MerchantUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {

    Optional<Users> findByIdAndTypeIn(Integer id, String... types);
}
```

Is there some way to limit the returned number of rows to 1?

Comment: Shouldn't `id` not already be unique?

Comment: Try this one `Optional<Users> findTop1ByIdAndTypeIn(Integer id,List<String> types)`

Comment: The method return a single object not a list. What exactly needs to be limited.

Comment: try `Optional<Users> findTop1ByIdAndTypeIn(Integer id, Collection<String> types)`

Answer (score 0):

You add a Pageable param to your query:

```
Optional<Users> findByIdAndTypeIn(Integer id, String... types, Pageable page);
```

For one result you create it like:

```
Pageable firstRow = PageRequest.of(0, 1);
```

You may consider adding a `Sort` object also for your query in that case

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this post.. why is it down voted.(To the Person who Down Voted)

Comment: One additional question: can I use specification with above example?